# AWS Elasticbeanstalk ruby platform with Passenger 5.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am planning to migrate my core instances from EC2 to Elasticbeanstalk Ruby with Passenger platform. After checking, I found this list:

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.ruby

What so interesting is that only Passenger(4.0.60) is available even with the most recent ruby(2.6.0). It seems AWS EB teams only update the Ruby but not the Passenger.

The 5.x has been released for years with many improvements, features and changes of workflow. Is the passenger ruby platform no longer in maintenance?

My current ec2 env is in 5.x, I feel more confident with this version.

Is there anyone having experiences how to get passenger 5.x up with EB?

I am open for any customizations and/or workarounds.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would like to know as well. I am experiencing this annoyance with 4.0.60 on beanstalk https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1730 it does not seems to cause any real issue other than noise in my error reporting system. I wish Beanstalk would offer 5.x and 6.x as an option. 4.x could remain for people deploying old rails 1.x 2.x apps since Passenger 5.x removed the support for legacy rails.